# broken file icon retrieving image from database php and mysql

Tags: php, database, image, blobstorage

I need to upload and retrieve image from a database, I am able to store the image in the database but unable to display it later. please help
I wrote the following code to retrieve from the database.

```
  $result1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO userdata(id, username, firstname, lastname, imageType, image)VALUES('', '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['firstname'] . "', '$lastname','{$image_size['mime']}','{$imgData}')") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
if($result1)
{
echo "</br>";
echo "Registration successful";
echo "</br>";
echo $lastid=mysql_insert_id();//get the id of the last record
echo "uploaded image is :"; ?>
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" /><br/>

<?php
echo "</br>";     
}#if result1into db successful
else 
{
echo $result1;
echo "Problem in database operation";
```

imageView.php has the following code:

```
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("wordgraphic") or die(mysql_error());
         if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT imageType,image FROM userdata WHERE id=". $_GET['image_id'];
        $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);
        echo $row["image"];
         }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

What could be possibly wrong with the code?
When i try to run `imageView.php` with static id image is getting displayed. So i guess the error is in passing the variable is this code:

```
 echo "uploaded image is :"; ?>
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" /><br/>
<?php
```

what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Why you use `if(isset($_GET['id']))` and you don't pass it using your URI ?

Comment: it is actually, <img src="imageView.php?id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" /><br/> that is typo error but making this rectification also yielding no result.

Answer (score 0):

just a smal rectification

```
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" />
```

instead of this 
 src = src path where u r saving the image file lets say in images folder that would be here `$imagedata` store the file name in the DB so that you can retreive it from the image folder

```
<img src="images/$imgData" width="your wish" height="your wish"/>
```

Comment: but i have saved image in database and not in folder and instead of <img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" /> it is actually <img src="imageView.php?id=<?php echo $lastid; ?>" />    lastid is the id of image last inserted and i want dt image to be displayed.

Comment: instead of saving it in your db it is a best practise to save in with file upload in one folder and then save that file name to your DB and as i said in src place add that folder and followed by you image name which you stored in your DB by this way it is very easy, even to delete that image by simply using the unlink(folderpath/imagename)